# Giving index of list in ascending order

Tags: python-3.x

I need to sort an array, but giving the original indexs of the items. Sorry it is hard to explain via words.

Eg.

```
apple = 50 for 3 kg
pear = 100 for 5 kg
orange = 150 for 10 kg
```

```
list1 = ['apple','pear','orange']
```

I ready created a function to calculate the price per kilo, and I got a list returned:

```
[16.666, 20, 15]
```

and now I need to create a function to have list1 as parameter and turn `[2,0,1]`, that's the indexes of items in ascending order.

can't use np, and sorted doesnt seem to work

Comment: please post the function that you wrote, and the data you feed in. The first block of 'code' will throw an error in python.

Comment: I know, it wouldn't allow me to post it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want it sorted by price?

```
list1 = ['apple','pear','orange']
prices = [16.666, 20, 15]
indices = sorted([index for index in range(len(list1))], key=lambda x: prices[x])
print(indices) # Output: [2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Oh sorry I just realised I had a clerical error! so it should actually return the order according to the order of price, and I totally mess up..

Comment: Thats what it currently does. What do you mean?

Comment: sorry I was out of my mind, there was nothing wrong with your answer, can you show me hoe to make it into descending order please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Turn it to negative values for the key `key=lambda x: -prices[x]`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much